# Trying to call a method from a bean within my custom control

Tags: xpages

This code is in the beforePageLoadEvent of an xPage:

```
var aURL = eStarService.fetchDocLibraryDocumentURL( sessionScope.get( "PropertyNo" ), "Budget" );
sessionScope.put( "docURL",aURL );
var docUNID = eStarService.fetchDocLibraryDocumentUNID( sessionScope.get( "PropertyNo" ), "Architectural Change Form" );
sessionScope.put( "docUNID",docUNID );
```

It uses my eStarService bean to take a couple of parameters and fetch a document and get the url so I can open that document .  I can use this if I set the value of this method as a scope variable and use that scope variable in the custom contrl that contains the navigator code.

I would much prefer to call the method from my bean while in the custom control rather than rely on scope variables however when I access my bean in the custom control it throws an error about the class not being defined.  Yet it works fine inthe parent xPage.
thoughts?

Comment: more code. Where does it work and the code where it doesn't

Comment: At a minimum, include the actual text of the error message. The error may be enough to troubleshoot the behavior, but an approximate description of the error is not.

Comment: So I went back to recreate the error message and now it's working.  Go Figure.

I do notice however, the code executes every time the page loads rather than when the user clicks the link.  Here is the code I'm talking about:

<xe:navigator id="navigator1">
  <xe:this.treeNodes>
   <xe:basicLeafNode label="Budget">
    <xe:this.href><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var aURL = eStarService.fetchDocLibraryDocumentURL( sessionScope.get( "PropertyNo" ), "Budget" );
return aURL;
}]]></xe:this.href>
   </xe:basicLeafNode>
  </xe:this.treeNodes>
 </xe:navigator>

Comment: That's because this isn't an event, it's a dynamically determined component attribute. Your code is called when the XPage needs to determine what HTML to send to the browser, not when the user interacts with that HTML.

Comment: If you are wanting to create an onclick event on a basicLeafNode, then use the submitValue attribute, set an eventhandler on the component and check for that specific submitValue so you can then run your code.

Comment: I do want an onClick event in that navigation.  I'm trying to learn the best way to achieve that.  Can you show me a snippet of code how to do that?

Comment: There is already a similar stackoverflow example here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758208/onclick-event-in-outline-gets-executed-on-page-open...If you need a further example let me know.

Comment: Toby, I tried using the sample as you suggested.  Good news is it no longer executes the code on page load.  The bad news is it's not accepting a click.  When I hover vver the label it doesn't recognize it as a link thus it never executes the onItemClick event.  Can you see what I'm missing?

<xe:navigator id="navigator1">
 <xe:this.treeNodes>
  <xe:basicLeafNode label="New Bookmark" submitValue="NewBookmark"></xe:basicLeafNode>
 </xe:this.treeNodes>
 <xe:this.onItemClick><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent( "dlgNewBookmark" ).show();}]]></xe:this.onItemClick>
</xe:navigator>

Comment: I realize I am not checking for the submitted value in this code, as I was running out of characters for the comment I removed it

Answer (score 0):

Use custom properties computed once with $ not #